# Converting SharePoint 2010 REST code to SharePoint 2013 REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm a new developer to my department and I'm tasked with converting older URI's on our SharePoint site to REST API. Unfortunately I'm completely new to this, so I'm not sure how to go about it

The code the original developer used was on the the SharePoint 2010 platform. Unfortunately it no longer worked when we migrated over to the O365 platform.

It is supposed to display the SharePoint list information within tabs

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });
    $(function() {
        fnLoadFAQ('#FAQ-Container');
    });

    function fnLoadFAQ(container) {
        $.when(fnLoadFAQCategories(container)).done(fnLoadFAQContent(container));
    }       

    function fnLoadFAQCategories(container) {
        var url = '_api/web/GetList('List')/Items?$filter=Hide ne true&$orderby=Order';
        return $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var htmlOut = '<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified flex-container">';
            var faqContentHolder = '';
            $(data.d.results).each(function(index, item) {
                htmlOut  = '<li class="text-center"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#category-'   item.Id   '">'   item.Title   '</a></li>';
                faqContentHolder  = '<div id="category-'   item.Id   '" class="tab-pane fade" style="margin-top: 4px; padding-right: 4px;><div class="accordion"></div>';
            });
            htmlOut  = '</ul>';
            $('ul.nav-pills', container).html(htmlOut);
            $('.nav-pills > li:first').addClass('active');
            $('#FAQ-Content').append(faqContentHolder);
            $('#FAQ-Content > .tab-pane:first').addClass('in').addClass('active');
        });
    }

    function fnLoadFAQContent(container) {
        var url = '/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/List?$filter=Show ne false and Categories ne null&$orderby=Order';
        var faqs = {};
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $(data.d.results).each(function(index, item) {
                $(item.Categories.replace(/\s/mg, '').split(',')).each(function(count, key) {
                    if (faqs[key]) {
                        faqs[key].push(item);
                    } else {
                        faqs[key] = [item];
                    }
                });
            });

            $(Object.keys(faqs)).each(function(count, key) {
                var htmlOut = '';
                $(faqs[key]).each(function(index, item) {
                    var faq = '<div class="panel"><div class="panel-heading"><a style="display: block" class="faq-question collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"'
                           ' data-parent="'   container   '" href="#faq-'   key   '-'   item.Id   '">'   item.Question   '</a></div>';
                    faq  = '<div class="faq-answer panel-body collapse" id="faq-'   key   '-'   item.Id   '">'   item.Answer   '</div></div>';
                    htmlOut  = faq;
                });                 
                $('#category-'   key, container).html(htmlOut);
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to the stack. This is a pretty broad question without enough details. What part is not working? And how do you know? Are you familiar with your browser's debugger features? If so can you watch the network panel and see if there are any errors?

Comment: The list information is not displaying on the custom bootstrap page that was developed. The code set in place (as shown) is no longer calling the to SharePoint list. I have used the debug feature in chrome and can see no errors. I apologize if I'm still not being clear.